# PHP put_file_contents change file save path

Tags: php

i have this PHP:

```
file_put_contents($at[filename], $at[attachment]);
```

but im not sure what part is the file location, i want to be able to save the files in a different place - how can i change the save path?

will it work if i use...

```
file_put_contents($at[filename], "../ticket_attachments/".$ticketnumber."/".$at[attachment]);
```

Comment: RT[F]M: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 2):

pass the path where to save the file in the filename 1st parameter.

```
file_put_contents('../uploads/file_name.txt', $at[attachment]);
```